# Individual backround color for spinner items

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to color each item´s backround of the spinner individual. 
The items are set with this code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.duesentypen, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The hex values are stored in an array. Whereas the index count refers to the item count. E.g.:

```
String[] hex = {"#886da8", "#ffc3cf","#ef9b00", "#2bb430", "#f7dc01", "#bc65a2", "#487ebf","#e00124","#b36634","#949494", "#ffffff","#000000","#4bbbd0", "#8b6d9f", "#8ccff4"};
//color for the first spinner item: hex[0]
//color for the second spinner item: hex[1]
```

How could I do that in the best way?

Comment: Excuse me, you want to add a different color to each item or what?

Comment: Yes @Zain because each spinner item refers to a standardized color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom `Spinner` adapter and override `getView()` to set the color and text of each item.

Here I am wrapping colors around the array of colors using the modulus operator (%) in order to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsExecption` if the items are greater than the available colors.

**The custom adapter**

```
public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> mColors;
    private String[] mItems;

    ColorAdapter2(String[] items) {
        mItems = items;
        String[] hex = {"#886da8", "#ffc3cf", "#ef9b00", "#2bb430", "#f7dc01", "#bc65a2", "#487ebf", "#e00124", "#b36634", "#949494", "#ffffff", "#000000", "#4bbbd0", "#8b6d9f", "#8ccff4"};

        mColors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String color : hex) {
            mColors.add(Color.parseColor(color));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int args) {
        return mColors.get(args);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int args) {
        return args;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(mColors.get(position % mColors.size()));
        holder.textView.setText( mItems[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    /* Return spinner text of the item at particular position*/
    public String getItemAtPosition(int position) {
        if (position > -1 && position < mItems.length)
            return mItems[position];
        else
            return null;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myItems)));
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Color Activity</string>
    <string-array name="myItems">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
        <item>item4</item>
        <item>item5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Result

[image]

> **Edit**
>
> How can I get the text of the selected item?
>   spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString()
>   isn´t working anymore. The returned value is a big number.

Now as we created a custom adapter, then you have to customize any related data and you can't rely on the API of the default Spinner adapter; so I've added a `getItemAtPosition()` method above at the custom adapter that takes a position, and returns the text of this item.

**Usage**

```
String item = ((ColorAdapter)spinner.getAdapter()).getItemAtPosition(position));
```

And you can get it whenever an item is selected:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: " + 
              ((ColorAdapter)spinner.getAdapter()).getItemAtPosition(position));

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed solution, which worked well. Just one more question to make progress with my learning process in Java: The `spinner` is used in the `MainActivity`, should I make `ColorAdapter` an inner class of `MainActivity`or an own class in the MainActivity? Static or non-static?

Comment: @LudwigM it's up to you can do either of them from technical point of view; but imagine that you have multiple activities in your project, and some of them have spinners that require this adapter, so you need to copy your inner adapter class over and over again in each activity; so it's better to keep it as a separate class file, and just instantiate it in each activity. Also For the sake of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), it's better to separate functions into separate classes because each has different purpose.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I get the text of the selected item? `spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString()` isn´t working anymore. The returned value is a big number.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change color according to Position.

```
final List<String> plantsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(plants));

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.duesentypen, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item){
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;

        switch(position) {
             case 0:
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7C7967"));
             case 1:
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7C7967"));
                   }

                return view;
            }
        };

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```